# Como faço para retornar para "double" do df original?

Tags: r, data.frame

Quando converto o df de "factor" para "numeric" os valores se tornam inteiros. Como faço para retornar para "double" do df original?

```
df <- read.csv2(file.choose())

View(df)
str(df)  

df1 <- as.numeric(df[1:12])  
df1 <- as.numeric(unlist(df))
df1 <- lapply(df, as.numeric)
```

Também já tentei dessa forma e não consegui

```
df3 <- as.double(df[1:12]) 
df3 <- as.double(unlist(df))
df3 <- lapply(df,as.double)

str(df1)

df2 <- as.data.frame(df1)
View(df2)
```

***Resumindo:***

```
head(df)
  fixed.acidity volatile.acidity citric.acid residual.sugar chlorides
1           7.4              0.7           0            1.9     0.076
2           7.8             0.88           0            2.6     0.098
3           7.8             0.76        0.04            2.3     0.092
4          11.2             0.28        0.56            1.9     0.075
5           7.4              0.7           0            1.9     0.076
6           7.4             0.66           0            1.8     0.075


head(df2)
  fixed.acidity volatile.acidity citric.acid residual.sugar chlorides
1            71               77           1             11        40
2            75              113           1             31        62
3            75               89           5             26        56
4            13               13          57             11        39
5            71               77           1             11        40
6            71               69           1             10        39
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(valores = as.factor(c(1.1, 2.0, 3.3, 1.1, 1.0, 2.0)))

df$valores_num <- as.double(as.character(df$valores))
df$valores_num
```

Pode tentar converter para 'string' primeiro e depois como double.

Saída:

```
1.1 2.0 3.3 1.1 1.0 2.0
```

Verificando o data.frame:

```
str(df)
 $ valores    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","1.1","2",..: 2 3 4 2 1 3
 $ valores_num: num  1.1 2 3.3 1.1 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar ver quais as colunas que são de classe `"factor"`. Serão estas as colunas a transformar.

```
str(df)
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ fixed.acidity   : Factor w/ 3 levels "7.4","7.8","11.2": 1 2 2 3 1 1
# $ volatile.acidity: Factor w/ 5 levels "0.28","0.66",..: 3 5 4 1 3 2
# $ citric.acid     : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","0.04","0.56": 1 1 2 3 1 1
# $ residual.sugar  : Factor w/ 4 levels "1.8","1.9","2.3",..: 2 4 3 2 2 1
# $ chlorides       : Factor w/ 4 levels "0.075","0.076",..: 2 4 3 1 2 1
```

Isto pode ser obtido programaticamente com

```
ind_cols <- sapply(df, is.factor)
ind_cols
#   fixed.acidity volatile.acidity      citric.acid   residual.sugar        chlorides 
#            TRUE             TRUE             TRUE             TRUE             TRUE
```

Este índice lógico pode ser usado diretamente no que se segue, mas tendo em conta que na pergunta as colunas em causa estão definidas por um vetor númerico dado, `1:12`, também vou usar um vetor previamente definido, com menos colunas, as dos dados exemplo.

Para transformar as colunas, é necessário ter o índice de colunas tanto no data.frame resultado como no data.frame ao qual vai ser aplicada a função anónima.

```
ind_cols <- 1:5
df[ind_cols] <- lapply(df[ind_cols], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Verificar o resultado.

```
str(df)
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ fixed.acidity   : num  7.4 7.8 7.8 11.2 7.4 7.4
# $ volatile.acidity: num  0.7 0.88 0.76 0.28 0.7 0.66
# $ citric.acid     : num  0 0 0.04 0.56 0 0
# $ residual.sugar  : num  1.9 2.6 2.3 1.9 1.9 1.8
# $ chlorides       : num  0.076 0.098 0.092 0.075 0.076 0.075
 
head(df)
#  fixed.acidity volatile.acidity citric.acid residual.sugar chlorides
#1           7.4             0.70        0.00            1.9     0.076
#2           7.8             0.88        0.00            2.6     0.098
#3           7.8             0.76        0.04            2.3     0.092
#4          11.2             0.28        0.56            1.9     0.075
#5           7.4             0.70        0.00            1.9     0.076
#6           7.4             0.66        0.00            1.8     0.075
```

## Nota

O problema está resolvido acima, mas este problema é tão frequente que talvez seja desejável ter uma função que transforme um objeto de classe `"factor"` em um objeto de classe `"numeric"` ou `typeof` `"double"`, o que é idêntico. Para isso, pode-se tirar partido do sistema de classes S3 e escrever um método para `as.numeric` ou `as.double`.

Da documentação, `help("as.numeric")`:

> as.numeric is a generic function, but S3 methods must be written for as.double. It is identical to as.double.

Tradução:

> as.numeric é uma função genérica, mas os métodos S3 devem ser escritos para as.double. É idêntica a as.double.

Ou seja, o método vai ser escrito para `as.double` e tanto o nome de método S3 `as.double` como o nome  `as.numeric` chamam o mesmo método.

```
as.double.factor <- function(x) as.double(as.character(x))
```

Agora o seguinte código obtém o resultado pretendido.

```
ind_cols <- 1:5
df[ind_cols] <- lapply(df[ind_cols], as.double)  # ou as.numeric
```

## Dados

```
df <- read.table(text = "
  fixed.acidity volatile.acidity citric.acid residual.sugar chlorides
1           7.4              0.7           0            1.9     0.076
2           7.8             0.88           0            2.6     0.098
3           7.8             0.76        0.04            2.3     0.092
4          11.2             0.28        0.56            1.9     0.075
5           7.4              0.7           0            1.9     0.076
6           7.4             0.66           0            1.8     0.075
", header = TRUE)

df[] <- lapply(df, as.factor)
```